# Complex numbers in arithmetic progression concyclic?

Tags: complex-numbers

Do three complex numbers, which form an arithmetic series , lie on a circle in the argand plane?
As per I think, any three points can be concyclic as they will lie on the circumcircle of their triangle ( unless they are collinear).
How much is that true?

Comment: $1, i, 2i-1$ are in arithmetic progression and they are collinear. In general, if $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are in AP, they are colinear since $\frac{z_1+z_3}{2} = z_2$ and $z_2$ is the mid point of the line joining $z_1, z_2$

Comment: But that can not always be true.

Comment: Question is whether it can be concyclic or not?